# Нельзя получить GET параметр не из корневой страницы сайта, как исправить?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess, apache

При `http://example.com/?lang=en`  get запрос `$_GET['lang']` возвращает значение, но при `http://example.com/vrv?lang=en` не возвращает.

Где и как поменять чтобы получить get запросы?

Вот .htaccess файл:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteBase /  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял- Вы хотите такой вариант:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?q=$1&%1 [L]
```

Тестировать `.htaccess` можно здесь:
http://htaccess.mwl.be/